# ltm package 2PL model: how to calculate ability

Tags: r

I am using ltm package in R, an following this sequence:

```
library(ltm)
fit2 <- ltm(LSAT ~ z1)
factor.scores(fit2, resp.patterns = rbind(c(0,1,1,0,0), c(0,1,0,1,0)))
```

I obtain the following result:

```
Call:

rasch(data = LSAT)  

Scoring Method: Empirical Bayes

Factor-Scores for specified response patterns:

  Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 Item 4 Item 5 Obs   Exp     z1 se.z1

1      0      1      1      0      0   0 0.944 -0.959 0.801

2      0      1      0      1      0   0 2.744 -0.959 0.801
```

I would like to know what is the meaning of the numbers Exp, z1 and se.z1 and if its possible to calculate the ability value of this two patterns of results with those values. I want to use these values to generate a function that calculates ability in order to use the results out of R.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I assume `factor.scores` should have fit3 instead of fit2

Comment: Yes you are right! I have corrected the source code. Thanks!